# Semi-opaque red coloring spots on LCD, potentially dead pixels

Tags: lcd, monitor, optics

I've been researching how LCD screens work on a technical level. One thing I had a hard time finding any detailed information about is failure modes and how to identify the cause of failures.

Are there any good sources to read up on this?.

A specific example I've been trying to diagnose is the following picture.
The LCD screen has, as shown in the picture below, a semi-opaque red colored spot on it.

[image: Screen issue]

I've been having a hard time diagnosing what part of the LCD screen is failing here. I don't think it can be stuck pixels since there is still some transparency of the intended image. Secondly, the very sharp edges of the spot, I don't think it is any dirt or dust between any of the layers.

I think it could be a type of dead pixels but I am uncertain about the details of why it discolors in such a way and what would potentially cause it. I assume its some defect in the liquid crystal layer however I don't fully understand the physical explanation as to why it would discolor in such a way.

Comment: looks like either something smeared on the face of the screen or physical damage to the LCD layers

Comment: The glass is cracked, and moisture/gasses from the atmosphere is starting to diffuse into and degrade the liquid crystal fluid.